# regex (?!) and (?=) and null match

Tags: regex

im learning regex by Jim Hollenhorst's [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)
and I checked these two regexs the title mentioned in his software(Expresso), i found that `(?=)` is match a null char to every position in the text string, and `(?!)` is always fails
and i found myself a lot of difficult to understand the null char and empty match.something i felt i've caught it,but at the same time it seemed intangible .

so I hope some one can explain the "null" match (how it works,and some similar usages or regex) for me.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?=foo)` matches any position that's followed by `foo`, and `(?!foo)` matches any position that's *not* followed by `foo`. So, since every position is followed by the empty string — there's an empty substring between any two characters, and there's an empty substring at the start and end of any string — `(?=)` matches any position at all, and `(?!)` doesn't match any position at all.

Comment: hi! thanks for your explaination. does it mean that when i write a regex like `"abc"` is actually  `"\(null)a\(null)b\(null)c\(null)"` and the `\(null)` type contains some exp like `"\b" "^" "$" "z"` ...etc? so regex like `"^it\b\s"`  is run as `"^i\(null)t\b\s\(null)"`?

Comment: @user2166063: I wouldn't put it quite like that. It just means that there are length-zero strings everywhere; for example, the string `"ab"` = `"a" + "b"` = `"a" + "" + "b"` = `"" + "a" + "" + "b" + ""`. This isn't really specific to regexes.

Answer (score 3):

`(?=)` and `(?!)` are degenerate cases of a positive look ahead `(?=regex)` and negative look ahead `(?!regex)` respectively.

`(?=)` means the next part of the input matches the zero-width string (the point between adjacent characters or the last character and the end of input), which is always true.

`(?!)` means the next part of the input must *not* match the zero-width string, which is always false - there's always a nothing following every character.

Comment: thank for answer. so can i said that there's a null zero-width string in these exp but we just can't express it explicitly?and does the zero-width string have some other explicit forms like `\b $ ^ \z`?

Comment: Some expressions are zero-width, like your examples (there are others too, `\A`, `\Z`, etc), but the null expression has no useful purpose.